# React Native async await dispatch store

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, async-await, react-redux, react-hooks

So I want to make a login feature, in here server will validate first if the username or password is correct or not.
I'm using store, react - redux.

Here is my code when login button pressed

```
const [statusLogin,setStatusLogin] = useState(null)
let loginInfo = []

function loginButton(){
    (async () => {
            loginInfo = {username:username,password:password}
            const { status } = await dispatch(getUser(loginInfo))
            if (status==1){
                console.log(status,'in status if 1')
                setStatusLogin('granted')
            }else{
                console.log(status,'in status if else')
                setStatusLogin(null)
            }
    })();
}
```

Here is my store that suppose to return value 1 or else
if it returned value 1 geb statusLogin will changed as granted

```
export function getUser(body){
    return dispatch =>{
        if (!body){
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('no username/pass')
            }, 2000);
        }else{
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('username/pass validated returning with value 1')
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
}
```

help me please

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
...
function loginButton() {
  (async () => {
    loginInfo = { username: username, password: password };
    await dispatch(getUser(loginInfo, callback));
  })();
}

function callback = (status) => {
  if (status == 1) {
    console.log(status, "in status if 1");
    setStatusLogin("granted");
  } else {
    console.log(status, "in status if else");
    setStatusLogin(null);
  }
};
```

reducer.js

```
export function getUser(body, callback){
    return dispatch =>{
        if (!body){
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('no username/pass');
                callback(0);
            }, 2000);
        }else{
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('username/pass validated returning with value 1')
                callback(1);
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like:

```
usEffect(( )=>{
if(statusLogin) getUser()
},[statusLogin])
```

Another thing, your function should not passed callback in. Instead of using callback to change the state, you can use dispatch to modify the reducer.

Comment: I kinda use this at first but I think callback is better thanksss

Comment: using callback maybe easy for now. But it will be nightmare when you come to maintain or fixing bugs.
Passing callback will separate your logic code.
So it's the best to not use callback as parameter